# Redux createStore/applyMiddleWare Q

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am new with Redux and followed a tutorial on implementing redux in react. I'm having an issue that seems to be no value is being received in app.js from store.js's createStore function. Any ideas?

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppNavbar from './components/AppNavbar';
import ShoppingList from './components/ShoppingList';
import ItemModal from './components/ItemModal';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
         <Provider store={store}>
           <div className="App">
            <AppNavbar />
            <Container>
            <ItemModal />
            <ShoppingList />
          </Container>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

store.js

```
 import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
 import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
 import rootReducer from './reducers';

 const initialState = {};

 const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
);
```

export default store;

reducers folder
itemReducer.js - Just showing GET_ITEMS case

```
import {
  GET_ITEMS,
  ADD_ITEM,
  DELETE_ITEM,
  ITEMS_LOADING
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  items: [],
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
```

index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import itemReducer from './itemReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  item: itemReducer
});
```

Error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C://client/node_modules/redux/es/redux.js:523

```
  return funcs.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return function () {
      return a(b.apply(undefined, arguments));
    };
  });
}
```

createStore
C://client/node_modules/redux/es/redux.js:87

```
 throw new Error('Expected the enhancer to be a function.');
 }

 return enhancer(createStore)(reducer, preloadedState);
}

if (typeof reducer !== 'function') {
```

./src/store.js
C://client/src/store.js:9

```
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
rootReducer,
initialState,
compose(
```

Comment: what tutorial are you reading? where did you see that example of using createstore with the nested compose and applymidddlware the way you have it?

Comment: also, what does your rootreducer look like

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLillGF-RfqbbiTGgA77tGO426V3hRF9iE

His completed code is downloadable in the description

Comment: Edited question to include my itemReducer.js file (only GET_ITEMS action)
Also included index.js file that imports ./itemReducer

Comment: did you catch your error yet? (hint: you never use `middleware` anywhere)

Comment: I removed "window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()" and it all seems to be working

But perhaps there's another solution with middleware

Comment: can you post your updated code. what I mean is.. no where in the code you posted are you *using* the `middleware` variable

Comment: Edited the code inside createStore , yeah sorry I got what you meant I kind of followed along this part and am looking at redux docs on applyMiddleware to understand it more and understand it to know where to use the middleware var

Comment: cool. does that mean its fixed or that you're still reading the docs? next time your post a comment, update your code with the exact code you have and if any change in amend the new error to the question as well

Comment: Yes It's working as it should,  but I'm curious about what you said about not using the middleware variable as I didn't change anything related to that var - and appreciate that tips and help

Comment: Either way, got it going and gotta go. Appreciate the help! I honestly don't know how to upvote or add rep for you but I'll try in the morning lol !

Answer (score 0):

That error is related to the [Redux DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd) Chrome extension integration which enables you to view the Redux store visually in the browser. Installing [Redux DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd) extension should do the trick. If you do not wish to use the extension, you can simply omit the following code to remove the integration with the extension:

`,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()`